# Fallback if variable is empty

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a typoscript IMG_RESOURCE variable, filled with the url to an image from the page properties. If no Resource is found, I would like to have it fallback to some default value. 
But I can't figure out how to do this in typoscript. Here is what I have:

```
plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph.image = COA
plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph.image {
    10 = TEXT
    10.if.isFalse.data = lib.opengraphimage
    10.data = lib.opengraphimage
    10.wrap = |

    20 = TEXT
    20.if.isTrue.data = lib.opengraphimage
    20.data = FALLBACK IN HERE
    20.wrap = |
}
```

`lib.opengraphimage` is the IMG_RESOURCE. This doesn't work. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where is the Typoscript reference for the typoscript terms `plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph.image` and `lib.opengraphimage`? I cannot find it in the metaseo extension documentation. - To my opinion you have mixed up different typoscript types which won't work like this. Please be more specific.

Comment: `plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph.image` adds the meta-tag `og:image`. This works fine. `lib.opengraphimage` is just a IMG_RESOURCE with an image from the backend page properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (untested):

```
plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph.image = COA
plugin.metaseo.metaTags.opengraph.image {
    10 = IMAGE
    10.file = fileadmin/path-to-yout-image
    10.override.if.isTrue.data = lib.opengraphimage.file
    10.wrap = <meta property="og:image" content="|">
}
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Image/Index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your assignement

```
  *.data = lib.opengraphimage
```

is not correct. As you said lib.opengraphimage is an IMG_RESOURCE, a typoscript object you can't assign it this way to a stdWrap property (data).

`.data` is used with fields or variables.

you propably want to use it in a way like

```
 *.if.isTrue.cObject < lib.opengraphimage
```

in this way the typoscript definition of `lib.opengraphimage` is copied and evaluated before checked.

Be aware of the optimizations Heinz Schilling tried to show you:

- use `stdWrap.override` instead of a COA with two alternatives which each got an .if wrap
- you might not need the whole IMG_RESOURCE but only the used file to decide which variant to use